# Rollback on multiple queries

Tags: mysql, database

How can I do multiple queries, the usen commit(), and if something goes wrong, rollback all queries?

I noticed that if I wrap my queries and commit with inside try / catch, only the unsuccesful queries are rolled back

```
try{

  $pdo->beginTransaction();

  // create 10 tables
  foreach($queries as $query)
    $result = $pdo->query($query);

  $pdo->commit();

}catch(PDOException $e){

  // here if one of the tables fail to be created, undo all operations
  $pdo->rollBack();  

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL does not support embedded transactions.

If you think you are getting a partial rollback, you are checking it wrong. In particular, an *unsuccesful query* will not even run, so there's nothing to rollback there. What happens is that you don't really have a transaction, either because you forgot the `START TRANSACTION` statement or because your tables are not InnoDB.

**Edit:** I've just seen you've updated your question. You cannot rollback DDL statements such as `CREATE TABLE`. You can only rollback DML statements (`SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`...). This is not a MySQL limitation, it's the standard behaviour in all DBMS engines I know.

Answer (score 3):

You may have the following scenario:

- Perform 10 SQL Statements
- Rollback 5 SQL Statements
- Perform 10 SQL Statements
- Rollback 12 SQL Statements

The only way to pull off something of this nature is to use checkpoints. In terms of InnoDB and transaction processing, they would be called savepoints.

While you have START TRANSACTION, COMMIT and ROLLBACK commands for handling whole blocks of SQL statements in a single transaction, you will have to manually injection a savepoint between groups of SQL Statements.

**EXAMPLE** : If you run the following sequence of transactions

- `INSERT` 10 rows
- `SAVEPOINT savepoint1`
- `UPDATE` 3 rows
- `SAVEPOINT savepoint2`
- `DELETE` 7 rows
- `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT savepoint1`

The result is that the 7 DELETEs and the 3 UPDATEs are gone from the InnoDB redo logs, but the 10 INSERTs are still in the logs and available for any dirty reads until you one of the following:

- `COMMIT;`
- `ROLLBACK;`
- `RELEASE SAVEPOINT savepoint1`
- Introduce additional DML after savepoint1

There may not be a such a support mechanism within PHP or PDO, but MySQL/InnoDB does indeed have such SQL for it.

Please read this section of the MySQL Documentation on how to run [**SAVEPOINT and ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT**. There is also info on removing savepoints without COMMIT or ROLLBACK going off](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/savepoint.html).

I just read Brian Fisher's comment and it is true that MySQL cannot rollback table creation (Oracle can). In fact, any table DDL will commit any uncommitted data and start a new transaction.

Answer (score 1):

```
try{

  $pdo->beginTransaction(); 
  foreach($queries as $query)
    $result = $pdo->query($query);

  $pdo->commit();

}catch(PDOException $e){
  $pdo->rollBack();  
}
```

Comment: that doesn't work. I have beginTransaction but I still get 3 tables created, even if there's an error in creating the fourth

Comment: Ah, you want to handle the creation of tables in a transaction.  MySQL doesn't support rolling back the creation of tables.